# throwing an error 'Maximum call stack Size exceeded' when trying to convert from json to xml

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xml2js, js2xml

I have below xml

```
<measureDef><formula><aggFunction type="sum"><expression><field>ADMIT</field><factTable>ADMIT</factTable><aggregation>SUM</aggregation></expression></aggFunction></formula></measureDef>
```

and I have converted into json as

```
let dimensionJson = { "measureDef":{                
                        "formula": {
                           "aggFunction": {
                            "_attributes": {
                                "type": "sum"
                            },
                              "expression": {
                                 "field": "ADMIT",
                                 "factTable": "ADMIT",
                                 "aggregation": "SUM"
                              }
                           }
                        }            
                }
}
```

Now,in some case I want to convert this Json to xml.So,I'm trying to convert

```
const xml2JsonOptionsDefault = { compact: true, spaces: 0 };
    console.log('FORMULA ARRAY', convert.js2xml(dimensionJson, xml2JsonOptionsDefault));
```

It is throwing 'maximum call stack size exceeded'.Could someone tell me why it is happening?

Comment: Have you checked this issue on the repo: https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js/issues/21 ?

Answer (score 0):

From [a similar issue](https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js/issues/21) in the repo:

> ... you probably missing `"_text"` property in your json input. For
>   example, `{"a": "hi"}` will not produce `<a>hi</a>`. The correct input
>   is `{"a":{"_text":"hi"}}`.

This is untested, but you might need to include a "_text" property for any properies in your JSON that are going to have values in the XML.

Example:

```
let dimensionJson = {
    "measureDef": {
        "formula": {
            "aggFunction": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "type": "sum"
                },
                "expression": {
                    "aggregation": {
                        "_text": "SUM"
                    },
                    "factTable": {
                        "_text": "ADMIT"
                    },
                    "field": {
                        "_text": "ADMIT"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```